# Слишком большое время TTFB из-за Passenger

Tags: apache, ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache2

Использую Apache2, ROR. Реализую загрузку файлов на сервер через веб форму, стандартным образом протоколом HTTP метод POST. Сам процесс:

1. Указываю в форме файл для загрузки и отправляю, к примеру 40мБ.
2. Браузер начинает загружать 1%..100%, затрачивает 17секунд.
3. Далее браузер пишет ожидание, затрачивая 25сек

После этого всего файл загружен на сервер. После загрузки апачем файла в upload_tmp_file, passenger проводит какие-нибудь действия с ним, вроде кэширования или проверки целостности? Заметил один момент, если приостановить загрузку страницы, или уйти с нее, в момент когда начинается этот промежуток в 25сек, то файл сразу появляется в папке не поврежденный. Интересует, именно Passenger(его видно в процессах) что делает с файлом после того, как апач загрузил его в tmp? И пока это действие(над файлом) не завершится, экшен upload не будет работать, тем самым не отрендерит страницу и не передаст ее пользователю. В итоге получается это ожидание в 25сек..

**Обновление**

Использую Ror, загружаю файл 80мб на сервер(apache), используя протокол(http),  появляется очень большая задержка "ожидание". Загрузка проходит 1..100%, далее долгое ожидание TTFB. Виноват на мой взгляд passanger, тк засекал, где теряется время, а что конкретно не так не пойму.. С маленькими файлами все быстро.. Использую обычный метод загрузки. Вопрос: нормальна ли такая задержка как на картинке либо чем она обусловлена?

[image: Непонятно]

Comment: Весь метод upload проверял на время. Делал замеры скорости выполнения. Все нормально.

Comment: Где бы ни висело приложение эти 25 секунд, это было не в Rails. Возможно, запрос висел в Apache. Посмотрите по логам что в течение этих 25 секунд говорит Apache. Появляются ли записи об обслуживании этого запроса **до** или **после** этих 25 секунд.

Comment: После того как в браузере прошла загрузка файла 1%-100%.
Браузер пишет ожидание, в этот момент на сервере процессор на 95%-98% загружен процессом ruby2.3. Что в этот момент происходит?
Руби скрипт копирует принятый файл из upload_tmp_file в нужную мне директорию, с какой нибудь проверкой файла?

Comment: Ваша ж система. Можно попытаться поставить Rack Mini Profiler и у него глянуть Flamegraph, но скорее всего там этих 25 секунд не будет. Лично я бы посоветовал выкинуть Apache совсем и использовать связку из Ruby-специфичного сервера и nginx.

Comment: А после загрузки апачем файла в upload_tmp_file, руби проводит какие нибудь действия с ним, вроде кэширования или проверки целостности? Заметил один момент, если приостановить загрузку страницу, или уйти с нее, в момент когда начинается этот промежуток в 25сек, то руби выполняет какие-то действия(скорее всего с файлом) и файл сразу появляется в папке не поврежденный. Интересует, что делает руби с файлом после того как апач загрузил его в tmp?

Comment: И пока руби не сделает с файлом своё "грязное дело", он не хочет рендерить и посылать новую страницу.

Comment: Допишите это в вопрос.

Comment: Не в новый вопрос, прямо в этот.